# Edquota editing user settings via PHP

Tags: php, centos

I'm trying to automate the process with my ftp user creation, however I need to be able to set the quota of a user via PHP, in ssh I would use edquota username however if there a way to do this via PHP with SSH2 or ftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Exec command http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
exec('edquota username');
```